# How to replace a service provider configured in odata AddRouteComponents in integration test?

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, integration-testing

I've already known how to replace a service in asp.net core in integration test as per:
[replace-service-with-mocked-using-webapplicationfactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53507352/replace-service-with-mocked-using-webapplicationfactory)

But the added services when AddRouteComponents() seem to be added to a different container.
The solution above won't work with these services.

How can I replace those services in an integration test with WebApplicationFactory?

Comment: Do you want to modify the route pattern duing the test?

Comment: @RuikaiFeng I don't want to modify the route pattern, I just want to replace the ODataBatchHandler with a mocked object during my integration test.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to create an OData service and do unit as well as integration testing, then check out the NRSRx framework here:  https://github.com/ikemtz/NRSRx.

Using this framework you should be able to accomplish 100% code coverage.  Also check out the sample OData and OData test projects: https://github.com/ikemtz/NRSRx/tree/master/samples/IkeMtz.Samples.OData.Tests.

To make getting started easier, check out this VS extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ikemtz.NRSRxExtensions